# Help to keep plants watered without overwatering and prevent burning the leaves?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, containers, palm, monstera

I have a Majesty Palm and a Monsterra I am trying to grow so I followed the instructions on the tag to water once a week. But I live in a dry environment so by end of the week, both had yellowing of branches and leaves so I watered them again. But then they were both drooping *(assumingly from overwatering despite being in pots with drain holes)* so I asked someone how to fix that and they recommended putting them outside in the sun to help the plants by evaporating the moisture in the pot's soil. But I put them outside for 1 day and now they both have burned leaves.

Can anyone tell me how to prevent the plants from drying out while also avoiding overwatering them? And also how to prevent plant leaves from getting burned?

Answer (score 1):

The way to effectively water houseplants is always to check the surface of the soil by feeling it to see if it feels dry to the touch; if it is and the soil in the pot has shrunk from the sides of the pot, that's too dry, but if it's dry to the touch, and if the pot feels a little light in weight if you are able to pick it up, it needs watering. When you water, water thoroughly, letting the excess drain away freely from the bottom of the pot, and being sure to  empty out any outer pot or tray 30 minutes after watering, and again 30 minutes after that if more collects, so the plant is not left sitting in water. Unless you leave your plants sitting in water, or in a pot with no or blocked drainage holes, the soil will dry out over time, there is no need to take action to encourage this.

Never, ever put a houseplant straight outside in direct sun for any length of time at all - plants in the house are not adapted to direct sun nor outdoor conditions, and must be slowly acclimatised to those conditions should you want to stand them outdoors for a time. This can be achieved by standing the plant outdoors when its warm enough, but NOT in direct sunlight, and bringing back inside after an hour or so, extending the time its left outside over a week or two. Exposing them bit by bit to direct sun, first as dappled shade, then maybe half an hour of sun (not at midday), extending the time over the next couple of weeks should help protect them, but bear in mind not all plants appreciate direct sunlight for long hours, even if they are growing outdoors from the start. *Monstera*, for instance, grows in jungles/forests and uses its aerial roots to climb up into the canopy of the surrounding trees, which means the plant grows best in humid, shadier conditions. I'd suggest you don't put them outside in direct sun again to prevent any further damage.